# How to use azure-sb in aurelia

Tags: azure, aurelia

The specific package I am attempting to use is `azure-sb`.

I am not sure what special steps Aurelia requires of me to use this package. In a fresh Node.js Web Application I can use the following steps and I can use the package just fine:

1. Create Project
2. run `npm install azure-sb --save`
3. add

   ```
   "dependencies": {
      "azure-sb": "0.10.4" 
   }
   ```

   to `package.json`
4. in `server.js` I can use `var azure = require('azure-sb');` and use all the functions provided by the package.

When I try something similar in Aurelia, I cannot use the package. 
As additional step, I add `azure-sb` to the `aurelia.json`.

```
C:\Projects\AureliaNotification>au import azure-sb
INFO [Importer] ---------------------------------------------------------
INFO [Importer] *********** Configuring azure-sb ***********
INFO [Importer] [OK] Going to execute the "Amodrotrace Strategy" strategy
INFO [Importer] *********** Finished configuring azure-sb ***********
INFO [Metadata] Adding/removing dependencies to the 'vendor-bundle.js' bundle
INFO [Metadata] The 'azure-sb' dependency has been added.
INFO [Tutorial] *********** Tutorial ***********
INFO [Tutorial] Are you the maintainer of azure-sb and would you like to define
a tutorial that is displayed here?
INFO [Tutorial] In order to do so you can add an "aurelia"."import"."tutorial" s
ection to the package.json of azure-sb. This can be set to an array of strings.
INFO [Tutorial] *********** Importing the module ***********
INFO [Tutorial] The following import statements are possible:
INFO [Tutorial] import 'azure-sb';
INFO [Tutorial] import azure-sb from 'azure-sb';
INFO [Tutorial] import * as azure-sb from 'azure-sb';
INFO [Tutorial] We are looking into ways to detect what is the right one
INFO [Tutorial] *********** End of tutorial ***********
INFO [Importer] ---------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is then that it looks for all azure-sb's dependencies in the wrong location.:

```
Tracing azure-sb...
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: C:/Projects/AureliaNotification/src/util.js
| Requested by: C:\Projects\AureliaNotification\node_modules\azure-sb\lib\servic
ebus.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it
 is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: C:/Projects/AureliaNotification/src/underscore.js
| Requested by: C:\Projects\AureliaNotification\node_modules\azure-sb\lib\servic
ebus.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it
 is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: C:/Projects/AureliaNotification/src/url.js
| Requested by: C:\Projects\AureliaNotification\node_modules\azure-sb\lib\servic
ebus.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it
 is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: C:/Projects/AureliaNotification/src/azure-common.js
| Requested by: C:\Projects\AureliaNotification\node_modules\azure-sb\lib\servic
ebus.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it
 is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
```

(+ many more)

I started to go through and add some of the dependencies to aurelia.json *by hand* but then I need to add those dependencies's dependencies etc, and some of them don't appear to actually exist.

Is there an option to tell Aurelia how to resolve the `requires` calls in the azure-sb package relative to the location of the javascript file that is doing the requiring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a NodeJS package, so it won't work with Aurelia, which runs in the browser.